# How to define excel SUMIFS criteria considering any text and numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

My SUMIFS formula criteria is based on a cell (say A1) that is data validated by list and changed via selection by user. If cell has data inside text or number by selection from drop down list, SUMIFS formula is considering that data as criteria to calculate the related sum. If criteria cell is left blank, I want formula to sum everything without any condition. My problem here; in criteria field of SUMIFS formula, I typed if condition like; `SUMIFS(sum-range,criteria_range,IF(A1<>"",A1,"*"))` but in this case excel considers only text values and do not include cells containing number. Briefly, if nothing selected in A1, I want SUMIFS formula to sum everything without any condition, numbers, texts and even blank cells. How can we proceed to do that?

EDIT:
Here an example for data and formula, what is expected is actually to disable criteria if one of selection is blank on left. Harun's suggestion works but if there is blank cell in criteria range, then in this case it won't consider those values in sum. For instance, if we select from left Phone/smart/touch, then how can we get "2" as output no matter what is in cri_range4 cells? Thanks

***Example:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution? It basically ignores a missing entry in column C and evaluates only the other two. (Your example formula has a fourth criterium that isn't apparent in your list but the method can be extended for as many criteria as you might have.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(LEN(C2),(INDEX(Lists,,1)=C2),TRUE))*(IF(LEN(C3),(INDEX(Lists,,2)=C3),TRUE))*(IF(LEN(C4),(INDEX(Lists,,3)=C4),TRUE))*SumRange)
```

For better readability I created a named range `Lists` which comprises your sample range E2:H10 while I named I2:I10 as `SumRange'.` INDEX(Lists,,1}` refers to the first column of the range. It's important that SumRange and Lists have the same number of rows.

Comment: Yes this might be a way but actually in my real formula there are many criterias not only one. So if I want to use this, I think it will be very long to create it..I want to do this in each of criteria field of my sumifs formula so I need to create a condition to consider all number text and blank cells.

Comment: The difference in the length of the formula is insignificant, regardless of the additional complications, maybe 20 characters at best, because providing for the extra inclusions also takes space. Whatever improvement over Harun's suggestion can be found will increase the formula size, too. However, the more other complications there are the greater the benefit of a clear distinction between the two methods of calculation when you think in terms of maintaining the formula.

Comment: yes but I think it will be amazingly long because there many combination. You can see added example in edit, maybe I explained better.

Comment: yes this seems great solution, just a question to clearly understand; it is filtering every critteria column if criteria cell is filled and at the end multiplying all 0 and 1 values and finally sum field with 1 values so as result filtered total, thats great but I just could not get how that IF condition field is working (LEN(C2))? Can you explain how it is checking if criteria cell is blank or not? THanks @Variatus

Comment: I think that one is working with ctrl shift enter, am I right? because I could not get it worked normally, any way to work as normal ? Thanks @Variatus

Comment: ah ok that LEN is giving zero if cell is empty, thats fine, but any way to get it worked without ctrl shift? thanks

Comment: SUMPRODUCT doesn't need to be entered as an array formula. I can't tell if this is an exception because it works as a normal formula on Office 365. I also see no reason why it should require Ctl+Shift+Enter. Have you tried?

Comment: now it is ok, that works great many thanks, you did great.. @Variatus

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the feedback. Please remember to mark the answer as "Selected"

Answer (score 0):

If `A1` is blank then just use not equal operator to sum all cells that are not blank. Try below.

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D5,C1:C5,IF(A1<>"",A1,"<>"))
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** can you check below formula in `D3` cell then drag down.

```
=IF(C2="",SUM($I$2:$I$10),SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$H$10=C2)*($I$2:$I$10)))
```

[image]

Comment: But I need blanks to be added to the sum too.

Comment: @IbrahimBayram Can you show us some of your data and expected output?

Comment: I've added @Harun24HR

Comment: @IbrahimBayram Then what will be output in `D3`, `D4`, `D5`, `D6` cell?

Comment: @IbrahimBayram can you please check edited formula.

Comment: output is in only one cell and depends on selection of many criterias. We need to evaluate all criterias at once and a crtieria can be disregarded only if selection is left blank. @Harun24HR

Comment: @IbrahimBayram So, as per your screenshot and formula what will be output?

Comment: should be 2. @Harun24HR